# Aggregating single orders to block orders.

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a number of orders. e.g. [A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2] = [*Account#, Side, Quantity, ticker, limit price, stop price*] - I would like a way to aggregate the orders first by the ticker, and then by the side. e.g. if I have 3 orders for Oil with quantities 2,5,4, with sides, Buy, Buy, Sell - I would like to have 2 rows with Buy 7 Oil and Sell 4 Oil. Any suggestions would be great. 
I don't have any sample code to reference as not sure where to start.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out in a fairly unconventional way, but works nonetheless. Easier to merge all the parameters, so that it truly distinguishes orders that are 100% the same excluding size. Then aggregate by size, then reverse the procedure. This way actually seems to make it fairly easy for me to maintain. 
[D = Side, E = Qty, F = Contract, G = Ticker, H = Expiry, I = LimitPx, J = StopPx, K = Notes, L = Notes]  - O & P are just blank/free columns.

```
Dim strFormula(1 To 1) As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORDERS")
LastRow = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORDERS")

strFormula(1) =   "=D4&""/""&F4&""/""&G4&""/""&H4&""/""&I4&""/""&J4&""/""&K4&""/""&L4"

.Range("O4:O4").Formula = strFormula
ws.Range("O4:O" & LastRow).FillDown

End With

Sheets("ORDERS").Range(Range("O4"), Range("O4").End(xlDown)).Copy
Range("O4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'********************************************************************

Dim OrderRng As Range
Dim Dic As Variant
Dim ordparam As Variant

On Error Resume Next

xTitleId = "ETS_TRADE_BLOCK"
Set OrderRng = Range(Range("A4"), Range("O4").End(xlDown))
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

ordparam = OrderRng.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(ordparam, 1)

    Dic(ordparam(i, 15)) = Dic(ordparam(i, 15)) + ordparam(i, 5)

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

OrderRng.ClearContents
OrderRng.Range("O1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)
OrderRng.Range("P1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'***************************************************************************

Dim reFormula(1 To 9) As Variant
Dim LastRows As Long
Dim wst As Worksheet

Set wst = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORDERS")
LastRows = wst.Range("O" & wst.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORDERS")

    reFormula(1) = "=LEFT(O4,FIND(""/"",O4)-1)"
    reFormula(2) = "=P4"
    reFormula(3) = "=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(O4,FIND("" | "",SUBSTITUTE(O4,""/"","" | "",1))+1,LEN(O4)),""/"",REPT("" "",LEN(O4))),LEN(O4)))"
    reFormula(4) = "=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(O4,FIND("" | "",SUBSTITUTE(O4,""/"","" | "",2))+1,LEN(O4)),""/"",REPT("" "",LEN(O4))),LEN(O4)))"
    reFormula(5) = "=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(O4,FIND("" | "",SUBSTITUTE(O4,""/"","" | "",3))+1,LEN(O4)),""/"",REPT("" "",LEN(O4))),LEN(O4)))"
    reFormula(6) = "=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(O4,FIND("" | "",SUBSTITUTE(O4,""/"","" | "",4))+1,LEN(O4)),""/"",REPT("" "",LEN(O4))),LEN(O4)))"
    reFormula(7) = "=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(O4,FIND("" | "",SUBSTITUTE(O4,""/"","" | "",5))+1,LEN(O4)),""/"",REPT("" "",LEN(O4))),LEN(O4)))"
    reFormula(8) = "=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(O4,FIND("" | "",SUBSTITUTE(O4,""/"","" | "",6))+1,LEN(O4)),""/"",REPT("" "",LEN(O4))),LEN(O4)))"
    reFormula(9) = "=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(O4,FIND("" | "",SUBSTITUTE(O4,""/"","" | "",7))+1,LEN(O4)),""/"",REPT("" "",LEN(O4))),LEN(O4)))"

.Range("D4:L4").Formula = reFormula
wst.Range("D4:L" & LastRows).FillDown

End With

Sheets("ORDERS").Range(Range("D4"), Range("L4").End(xlDown)).Copy
Range("D4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```